# How to use Facebook's FQL query using graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Is there a way to use Facebook's FQL query using the current graph API? Or we still have to use the legacy API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example of Graph API and JavaScript:**

```
FB.api(
    {
method: 'fql.query',
query: 'SELECT uid, first_name, last_name FROM user WHERE uid = ' + someUid
    },
    function(data) {
  // do something with the response
    }
);
```

- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/
- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

**Example Of Rest API:**

```
$data = $facebook->api( array( 'method' => 'fql.query', 'query' => 'SELECT shit FROM table...' ) );
```